# Android java how to get location as variable

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app where the user enters a name for his/her current location and then it will save the latitude, longitude and altitude in a simple sharedPreferences file...

Things I need :

I don't want is to use internet, because it will be used in an area where there is no cell signal.

I know it will probably take longer to load coordinates without internet.. So I want to ask if it is possible to use a progress bar to indicate when it is done??...

Thanks a lot to anyone who helps me :)

Comment: With no Internet where will you be "loading" these coords from?

Comment: Well, I have read that it is possible, but I couldn't find an explanation on HOW to do it..?

Comment: @takendarkk GPS could still be working, you don't need Internet or a cell phone signal for GPS to work.

Comment: I know that, but does the OP?

Comment: Yes I know but this is actually just part of an app that I'm making...

Comment: Suggest you narrow down what you are asking about and/or show an example of what you are trying (in code) and identifying what is stopping you make progress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use progress bar.

You can use location `Locationmanager` and `LocationListener` Model. In this model you will be given with all the callbacks you need.

Comment: No... You need set specially as GPS

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPS when you have no internet connection, and you can use location search (by any method you'd like) when you have internet connection. However, your request to enter the location name, then find its coordinates is impossible to do if you have no internet connection unless you keep a DB of all location names and their coordinates on your device, which is only possible if you make a rather short list of specific locations, a few countries at most.